# Can I set up ReSharper to rename unimported classes usages to their full names instead of importing their namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, refactoring, resharper

When I try to use a class whose home namespace is not imported with a using directive, a pop-up appears allowing me to choose the class (by its full name) and adds a using directive to import it.

In a project of mine I make heavy use of same-named classes from different namespaces and would prefer to specify a full name on every use.

Can I set up ReSharper to replace a class "first name" with its full name in-place instead of importing its home namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send this question to the ReSharper support team. They'll be happy to help you out. BTW, this feature is already in Visual Studio, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period) and select the full name.

I don't have this problem, and it works fine for me using Visual Studio and ReSharper side by side.